# How to set an array of the current year plus the next 5 years in Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set a dropdown select in Vue that defaults to the current year and includes options for the next 5 years. I think my code technically works, but I was wondering if there's a clear way to write it.

```
<select v-model="enrollYear" id="enrollYear" class="custom-select">
    <option v-for="year in years" :selected="selectedYear === year">{{ year }}</option>
</select>

data() {
    return {
        requestData: {
            enrollYear: null,
        },
        selectedYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
        years: [new Date().getFullYear() + 1,
               new Date().getFullYear() + 2,
               new Date().getFullYear() + 3,
               new Date().getFullYear() + 4,
               new Date().getFullYear() + 5
        ],
    }
},
```

Comment: `[...Array(6).keys()].map(i => new Date().getFullYear() + i)` is a nice one liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short way (and elegant) is something like

```
[...Array(6)].map((a,b)=> new Date().getFullYear() + b)
```

This will create an empty array  of length 6 `Array(6)` then it will spread it into an array to actually create the inside undefined elements `[...Array(6)]`

Then it just map over the newly created array and return the current Year + the current index.

It is good to know that `Array(6)` does not initialize the positions in the array, it just sets the length. That is why we need to spread it.

---

Another thing I noticed in your code is that there is no default date. When you add `v-model="enrollYear"` it actually sets the value of that element to anything is stored in `enrollYear` so it doesn't matter if you set an option `selected`, it wont be selected.

To set a default value to the dropdown simply set variable `enrollYear` to the current year.

---

This is your code with those changes stated above

```
<select v-model="enrollYear" id="enrollYear" class="custom-select">
    <option v-for="year in years">{{ year }}</option>
</select>

data() {
    return {
        requestData: {
            enrollYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
        },
        // This is the same that you have, just simplified
        years: [...Array(6)].map((a,b)=> new Date().getFullYear() + b),
    }
},
```